# Using react-spring, AnimatedFoo = animated(Foo) doesn't work -- or how to animate a Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

In [react-spring Basics page](https://react-spring.io/basics):

```js
const AnimatedDonut = animated(Donut)
```

because I think `<animated.div>` can work, but `<animated.Donut>` doesn't work.

So I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-breeze-ghdse

```
const AnimatedFoo = animated(Foo);
// ....

return <AnimatedFoo style={props}>I will fade in</AnimatedFoo>;
```

but it doesn't animated.  Is it supposed to be the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suppose to pass the `style` prop in React component, similar to whats happening with CSS-in-JS where you pass `className`.

```
// Add style prop
function Foo({ children, style }) {
  return <div style={style}>Hello World {children}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit youthful-roentgen-r5310]

Comment: thank you, it works. I have noticed both places have to call it `style`. We cannot call it `bar` and pass to `Foo` and use `style={bar}` there.  The `bar` has to be `style` as well